# check to see if tree has 0 or 2 children

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

How do I check to see if the entire tree is semi-perfectly has 0 or 2 nodes? Consider the following conditions:

- A node with 0 children is semi-perfect.
- A node with 1 child is NOT semi-perfect.
- A node with 2 children is semi-perfect if 
           (size-of-larger-child <= size-of-smaller-child * 3)

This is what I have so far:

```
public static boolean isLeafOrHasTwoChildren(Node t) {
    if (t.left == null && t.right == null) {
        return true;
    }

    if (t.left == null || t.right == null) {
        return false;
    }
    // Recurse down the tree
    return isLeafOrHasTwoChildren(t.left)
        && isLeafOrHasTwoChildren(t.right);
}
```

Size computes the number of nodes in the tree.

Answer (score -1):

Let's enumerate our conditions.

- You return true if all visited nodes are null.
- You return true if all visited nodes are defined.
- You return false otherwise.

Let's identify the first condition - `isLeaf` - as:

```
boolean isLeaf = t.left == null && t.right == null;
```

Let's define `hasAllChildren` as:

```
boolean hasAllChildren = !(t.left == null || t.right == null);
```

If we look closely, `!(t.left == null || t.right == null)` is the same as `t.left == null && t.right != null` due to DeMorgan's Law.  This allows us to express this fairly straightforwardly, and this is likely the piece you're missing.

Now, let's discuss recursive flow.  We want to walk down the entire chain of nodes, in a visit-left-right fashion. So, we want to check our conditions before we recurse.

Base case:   If we're not a leaf (implying we don't have all children), we return false immediately.

Recursive step: If we're a leaf or we have all children, we continue down the chain.

Let's try to express this.

```
public static boolean isLeafOrHasTwoChildren(Node t) {
   // Trivial case; if we have an undefined node, we've definitely reached a leaf.
   if (t == null) {
       return true;
   }

   boolean isLeaf = t.left == null && t.right == null;
   boolean hasAllChildren = !(t.left == null || t.right == null);

   if(isLeaf || hasAllChildren) {
       return isLeafOrHasTwoChildren(t.left) && isLeafOrHasTwoChildren(t.right);
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```